# how to select dynamic column in linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
public class EmployeerRequest
{
    public long EmployeeRequestID { get; set; }
    public long EmployeePolicyID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSrNo { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSequenceNo { get; set; }
}

List<EmployeerRequest> empRequestList = new List<EmployeerRequest>();

var r = empRequestList.Select(x => new
{ 
    EmployeeRequestID = x.EmployeeRequestID,
    EmployeePolicyID = x.EmployeePolicyID
});

var r = empRequestList.Select(x => new
{ 
    EmployeePolicyID = x.EmployeePolicyID,
    EmployeeSrNo = x.EmployeeSrNo
});

var r = empRequestList.Select(x => new
{ 
    EmployeeSequenceNo = x.EmployeeSequenceNo
});
```

I want to select dynamically columns in linq as given above depending upon column parameter which has been passed in parameter.How to give dynamic select?

Comment: What parameter are you talking about? And what are its possible values?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmployeerRequest
    {
        public long EmployeeRequestID { get; set; }
        public long EmployeePolicyID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeSrNo { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeSequenceNo { get; set; }

        List<EmployeerRequest> empRequestList = new List<EmployeerRequest>();
    }
    public class NoName
    { 
        public dynamic Test(int param, List<EmployeerRequest> empReqList)
        {
            dynamic r;
            switch(param)
            {
                case 1:
                    r = empReqList.Select(x => new
                    {
                        EmployeeRequestID = x.EmployeeRequestID,
                        EmployeePolicyID = x.EmployeePolicyID
                    }).ToList();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    r = empReqList.Select(x => new
                    {
                        EmployeePolicyID = x.EmployeePolicyID,
                        EmployeeSrNo = x.EmployeeSrNo
                    }).ToList();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    r = empReqList.Select(x => new
                    {
                        EmployeeSequenceNo = x.EmployeeSequenceNo
                    }).ToList();
                    break;
            }
            return r;
        }       
    }
```